# Criando Models que derivem IdentityUser ou utilizar a tabela AspNetUsers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, modelagem, asp.net-identity

Estou desenvolvendo um software de gestão para minha academia de ginástica.

Tenho Alunos, Professores e usuários do sistema.

Instalei o identity.

Criei um *model* chamada `Aluno` que herda do `IdentityUser`

```
  public class Aluno : IdentityUser
    {

        public int AlunoId { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        //etc
}
```

Agora iria criar os professores, logo pensei

```
Professor: IdentityUser
```

Porém não seria melhor utilizar a própria tabela já criada pelo identity `AspNetUsers`?

Estou um pouco confuso, pois depois vou colocar algumas roles do tipo "alunos","professores","admin","operador", etc., que será o nível de acesso no painel administrativo do sistema.

Modo de como faria então para adicionar Alunos.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Mas deu erro.
Object reference not set to an instance of object.

Comment: Como controlar as paginas através do Identity? Role X pode acessar pagina Y
Role Z pode acessar pagina J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Porém não seria melhor utilizar a própria tabela já criada pelo identity AspNetUsers?

Esta forma já usa esta tabela. O que acontece é que os *Models* criados derivando `IdentityUser` serão todos registros da tabela `AspNetUsers`.

> Estou um pouco confuso, pois depois vou colocar algumas roles do tipo "alunos","professores","admin","operador", etc que será o nível de acesso no painel administrativo do sistema.

Dependendo de como é a composição do seu *Model*, a filtragem por *Role* pode não ser necessária. *Roles* são interessantes quando não há clara distinção entre usuários. Como neste caso há uma distinção bem modelada, o permissionamento pode ser feito conferindo se o usuário existe como aquela derivação. Por exemplo:

```
// Se usuário é aluno
var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
var aluno = db.Alunos.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == userId); // retorna um Aluno
var professor = db.Professores.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == userId); // retorna null
```

Comment: mas se elas derivam, eu devo inserir um aluno como userManager.Create(aluno) ou db.Alunos.Add(aluno) ? se for a 2º opção o campo id (vvarchar(max)) q ele cria vai ficar em branco!

Comment: `UserManager.Create(aluno)`, sem problemas.

Comment: eu teria que criar um IdentityConfig, para cada um? aluno, prof e user?
pq o create deveria ter algo assim
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<Aluno>
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<Professor>, etc?

Comment: Não precisa. Por herança, o `UserManager` de `IdentityUser` aceita qualquer entidade derivada.